# What is the correct position for “fairly” in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, adverb-placement

In the following sentence, where is the correct position for adverb "fairly"?

> 1. Although capitalism has increased life expectancies throughout the
>    years, some antiglobalization movements have been critical of
>    corporate capitalism and blame it for not **fairly** improving conditions for all
>    countries.
> 2. Although capitalism has increased life expectancies throughout the
>    years, some antiglobalization movements have been critical of
>    corporate capitalism and blame it for not improving conditions **fairly** for all
>    countries.
> 3. Although capitalism has increased life expectancies throughout the
>    years, some antiglobalization movements have been critical of
>    corporate capitalism and blame it for not fairly improving conditions for all
>    countries **fairly**.

Comment: Much the same meaning.  3 maybe emphasizes the fairness aspect by placing the word at the end of the sentence.

Comment: Agreed with @Aidan. Sentence 3 puts the emphasis strongest upon the equitable distribution of condition improvement, which is likely what the writer intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all three are correct, and the meaning is much the same for all of them. Sentence 3 emphasizes
"fairly" a bit. Sentence 2 emphasizes "all countries", But in this case the difference is small, and the difference is largely one of style.